# Android - Changing height of bottom dialog to accomodate new text

Tags: android, textview, bottom-sheet

I have a fragment of code, activated by pressing a button:

```
           helpdialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_layout, null);

            helpdialog.setContentView( view );

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.splo);

               // Text to place in dialog omitted

            tv.setText( sp );

            helpdialog.show();
```

And my fragment_bottom_layout.xml layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/splo"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

It works fine most of the time, but there are occasions when text is appended to the textview or a very large piece of text is displayed, and in this case, it forces the top of the text to disappear or be truncated, like FIFO. How can I prevent this and resize the dialog to accommodate all text? I thought about setting the height of the bottom sheet to tv.getLineCount()*tv.getLineHeight() but I can't find an easy way to apply this to the dialog itself.

EDIT: upon further investigation, I've noticed another problem. If I open up a bottom dialog that contains a long piece of text, and scroll up so that the top of the dialog goes off the top of the window, when I scroll back down, the text that has gone off the top is missing. This could be connected to the problem I am having above.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your .show()

```java
                //androidX
                View bottomSheetInternal = helpdialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);


                /*
                not androidX use:
                View bottomSheetInternal = helpdialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                 */

                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setFitToContents(true);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setHideable(false);
```

Also try wrapping your textview within a scrollview

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/splo"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To see full demo
https://github.com/Gaineyj0349/BottomSheetBehaviourExample

Comment: Hi,
I had to change your code slightly                 View bottomSheetInternal = helpdialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
               BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED); 
When I opened up the dialog, it filled the entire vertical space of the screen, but would not allow me to scroll up to read the bottom.

Comment: btw, the only real difference is that I used helpdialog rather than builder in the first line of code.